# What is @ :: ARGS in Perl?

Tags: perl

I was reading some code and found (code accepting filename and command line parameters)

```
@ :: ARGS = ($0,@ARGV);
```

But, I am unable to understand the  first part of the expression.  What exactly it is doing?

Does it behave the same way as `@ARGS = ($0,@ARGV);` ?

Comment: The `::` denotes a namespace. See [here](https://perlmaven.com/namespaces-and-packages)

Comment: here `::` refers to the main package, which is the default package in Perl. Although both behaves the same but the difference is that in the former case, the array is explicitly placed in the main package, whereas in the latter case, it's assumed to be in the current package which can be different form the current package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main program you have your variable

```
$foo
```

but could also reach it via `$main::foo`
and also via

```
$::foo
```

If you include a .pm package e.g. `FOO`
then you can "peek" imto that namespace via `$FOO::something`.

The other way around:

A module can put something into the main namespace (of your original .pl).

```
@::ARGS =
```

and

```
@ARGS =
```

is the same if you use it in your main program

But from a sub module it is not the same: The one would write in a local variable while the other would write into main.